# What is the correct format of saving Lat/Long coordinates into database and assign into path in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, maps, polyline

I'm trying to fetch the coordinates of a rout from my database which contains a set of lat/long strings.

Suppose I saved a path information (lat/lng) in my table by this format:

```
{lat:36.26479895658131,lng: 49.99473060839841},{lat:36.20609142498267,lng: 49.860834734374976},{lat:36.114064680113565,lng: 49.61570228808591}
```

Here is the code for preparing the above result:

```
<script>
var coordinates= [];
document.getElementById("field12").value = coordinates;

function myFunction(latLng) //latLng is comming from myFunction(e.latLng)
{
     var str = latLng;
     var res = String(latLng).split("(");
     var res1 = String(res).split(")");
     var res2 = String(res1).split(",");
     var final = "{lat:"+res2[1]+",lng:"+ res2[2]+"}";
     coordinates.push(final);
     document.getElementById("field12").value = coordinates;
}
</script>
```

Now I'm going to assign this coordinates into path in my java script code. Imagine I put the string of coordinates into a var like below:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [];

function RetrieveRouteCoordinates() {
    $.post('retrieveRouteCoordinates.php', function(data) {
        var myObj1 = JSON.parse(data);

        for(var t = 0; t < 2; t++)
        {
            if(myObj1[t] != null)
            {     
                flightPlanCoordinates[t] = myObj1[t].routCoordinates;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And then, I set one of the path as an example like this:

```
poly.setPath(flightPlanCoordinates[0]);
```

Generally, I need to know is my coordinates format before inserting to database correct or not? if not show me the correct format of saving and then indicate how I can assign them into the poly.

Comment: it's not clear to me what the problem/question is. You never insert to database here, neither send the coordinates to the server. The sample shown at the top just lacks the `[]` around it to be valid.

Comment: @jeff if you see the first javascript block, I put the **var final** into database in my code, I didnt put the insert code becuase of the mass code.. I insert the lat&lng by the format I said. but I think it's incorrect, let me know what is the correct format of saving and how to set them into my poly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers (also known as "floats", "doubles", or "real numbers") can be specified using any of the following syntaxes:

example:

```
<?php
$a = 1.234; 
$b = 1.2e3; 
$c = 7E-10;
?>
```

please check the documentation about the float numbers is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)
You can use `number_format((float)$number, 14, '.', '');`
To retrieve them

```
for(var i = 0; i<location_array.length; i++)
    { var loc = location_array[i] ; //==>(12.77,  24.87)

        var split_arr1 = loc.split("(");
        var result_split_arr1 = split_arr1[1].split( ")" );
        var split_latLon = result_split_arr1[0];
 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(split_lat, split_lon);
        path.push(latLng)
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
        });
}

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: path,
       strokeColor: "#FF0000",
       strokeOpacity: 1.0,
       strokeWeight: 2,
       map: map
    });

}
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for.. if you recheck my question, u will understand that I can save the coordinates with this format {lat; 36.93837,lng:37.83773} without any problem but i dont know is that true or not?! and how to add it in my poly

Comment: Mehdi you save them as strings...you should use float.Data is always stored as the datatype of the column (well, unless you count null as a datatype. please go here it is explained the differece very well https://stackoverflow.com/a/10694517/9025311